# Difference between two foreign key approaches in code first Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, foreign-keys, ef-code-first

I am new to asp.net MVC and database. I found there are two ways to create a foreign key relation.

Approach #1:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Vehicle> vehicles { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string lic_number { get; set; }
}
```

and the second way is:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string lic_number { get; set; }
    public virtual Person person { get; set; }
}
```

Please tell me is there any difference in the two approaches.

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: There is also a 3rd way - having *both* collection and reference navigation properties. No difference from database standpoint. See [Entity Framework Relationships and Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are no differences between the two approaches, Both achieves the same goal. Just a different way of doing.

Below says Person has many Vehicles.

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual List<Vehicle> vehicles { get; set; }
}
```

Below says that Vehicle belongs to a Person

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public virtual Person person { get; set; }
}
```

So Both are same.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the approaches will be the same - creating relation one-to-many.

However, you may want to write your domain classes in the following way - having comfortable access to related properties both from two objects.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string lic_number { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

This will auto generate relations based on code. If you want to be explicit you while designing you may use Fluent Api approach. [Check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#fluent-api)

Answer (score 0):

You want to design that every `Person` has zero or more `Vehicles` and every `Vehicle` belongs to exactly one `Person`.

To express this more clearly, I would use both declarations. This will be easier for future readers of your code. Besides, your queries won't need a join.

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // every Person has zero or more Vehicles:
    public virtual ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LicenseNumber { get; set; }

    // every vehicle belongs to exactly one Person using foreign key
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
    public virtual Person Person {get; set;}
}
```

Maybe Owner would be a better name for the Owner of this Vehicle.

Note that I have declared all columns of the tables. The relations between the tables are declared virtual: they are not real part of the table.

I've changed the `List<Vehicle>` into `ICollection<Vehicle>`. After all, would `Vehicle[4]` have a defined meaning?

Apart from that this way your relations between the tables are more clear for the reader, your queries will be simpler:

"Give me the Id and names of all Persons that have two or more vehicles"

```
var result = myDbcontext.Persons
    .Where(person => person.Vehicles.Count >= 2)
    .Select(person => new
    {
         Id = person.Id,
         Name = person.Name,
    })
```

"Give me Ids and Names of all Persons with their vehicles that are older than ..."

```
var result = myDbContext.Persons.Select(person => new
{
    Id = person.Id,
    Name = person.Name,
    OldVehicles = person.Vehicles
        .Where(vehicles => vehicle.CreationDate < OldDate)
        .ToList(),
});
```

"Give me all old Vehicles together with the Id and Name of their owners"

```
var result = myDbContext.Vehicles
    .Where(vehicle => vehicle.CreationDate < OldDate)
    .Select(vehicle => new
    {
        LicenseNumber = vehicle.LicenseNumber,
        Owner = new
        {
             Id = vehicle.Person.Id,
             Name = vehicle.Person.Name,
        },
    });
```

By using the relations between the tables, you won't have to join on foreign key anymore. Entity Framework will understand that a join is needed (not sure whether this is also valid for ef-core)